# Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. (React-native )

Tags: react-native, npm, keyboard, scrollview, expo

I am receiving the error: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.

I am writing a React Native application.

```
interface RegisterScreenProps {
  navigation: NavigationContainerRef;
}

const RegisterScreen: FunctionComponent<RegisterScreenProps> = ({
  navigation,
}: RegisterScreenProps) => {
  const { container, headerLogo, headerTitle, body } = styles;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View>
        <TextInput value={'afasfasdfdsfssddfsdfsffasf'} placeholder={'My Input'} />
        </View>
        
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default RegisterScreen;
```

I have tried many solutions but did not get success. When I remove KeyboardAwareScrollView this code works fine. i need KeyboardAwareScrollView for TextInput.

Comment: Could you recreate this issue with an expo snack?

Answer (score 10):

This is an [issue from react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/issues/429), fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/commit/1fb7ed409e06f51dffcb8cdfd6ab206c2674c5d8) .

You need to upgrade your `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` version in package.json to a newer version (>= `0.9.2`, preferably use the latest stable version).