# Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child While Upgrading to 63.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am updating my react native application from 61.5 to 63.2 and am now getting the following error in the log and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

ERROR MESSAGE
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

```
in Unknown (at Login/index.js:191)
in Login (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (created by CardContainer)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (created by ForwardRef(CardSheet))
in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (created by Card)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (created by Card)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (created by Card)
in Card (created by CardContainer)
in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (created by MaybeScreen)
in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
in CardStack (created by KeyboardManager)
in KeyboardManager (created by Context.Consumer)
in RNCSafeAreaView (at src/index.tsx:28)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (created by StackView)
in StackView (created by StackView)
in StackView
in Unknown (created by Navigator)
in Navigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SwitchView)
in SwitchView (created by Navigator)
in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
in NavigationContainer (at App.js:57)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at App.js:52)
in PersistGate (at App.js:51)
in Provider (at App.js:50)
in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

Below is the code from the Login" screen that I think is the problem.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    Alert,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    Platform,
    Keyboard,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback,
    TouchableOpacity,
    PermissionsAndroid
} from 'react-native'
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Formik } from 'formik'
import _ from 'lodash'
import { ButtonGroup } from 'react-native-elements'
import { FormInput, Text, Button } from 'components'
import * as actions from 'redux/actions'
import { styles as appStyles } from 'common/styles'
import { w, m, h } from 'common/helpers'
import images from 'images'
import apiErrorsById from 'common/apiErrorsById'
import config from 'common/config'
import TosModal from './TosModal'
import InputModal from './InputModal'
import geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation'
import { isIphoneX } from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper'
const { colors } = appStyles

const buttons = ['Yes', 'No']

class Login extends Component {
    page = 'login'

    state = {
        selectedIndex: this.props.state.settings.saveUsername === true ? 0 : 1,
        tosModalVisible: false,
        inputModalVisible: false,
        inputValue: 'http://'
    }

    requestLocationPermissionAndroid = async () => {
        try {
            await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                {
                    title: 'Location Access Required',
                    message: 'This App needs to Access your location'
                }
            )
        } catch (error) {
            // console.log('location permission error', error);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            geolocation.requestAuthorization()
        } else {
            this.requestLocationPermissionAndroid()
        }
        if (!this.props.state.settings.TOSAccepted) {
            this.setState({ tosModalVisible: true })
        }

        const {
            settingsfileurl,
            enableautosettingsupdate
        } = this.props.state.settings.general

        if (enableautosettingsupdate) {
            this.props.getSettingsFromUrl(settingsfileurl, false)
        }
    }

    onSubmitEditing = (i, props) => {
        const nextInput = this['input' + ++i]
        nextInput ? nextInput.focus() : console.log('dont submitt') // this.onLoginPress(props)
    }

    componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
        const { settingsdownloaded } = nextProps.state.settings
        if (settingsdownloaded && this.state.inputModalVisible) {
            this.setState({ inputModalVisible: false }), () => {}
        }
    }

    rememberUserName = () => {
        const storeName = 'settings'
        const shouldRemember = this.state.selectedIndex == 0
        const { unitName, userName, password } = this.formikProps.values

        const newValues = [
            { prop: 'unitName', value: unitName },
            { prop: 'userName', value: userName },
            { prop: 'password', value: password },
            { prop: 'saveUsername', value: shouldRemember ? true : false }
        ]

        newValues.forEach(item => {
            this.props.valueChange({
                storeName,
                prop: item.prop,
                value: item.value
            })
        })
    }

    gatherLoginData = () => {
        const { values } = this.formikProps
        const loginData = {
            ...values,
            navigation: this.props.navigation
        }
        return loginData
    }

    onLoginPress = async () => {
        this.rememberUserName()
        const { password, unitName, userName } = this.formikProps.values;
        if (!password || !userName) {
            Alert.alert('Username, and Password are required.', '', [{ text: 'OK' }])
        } else {
            this.props.loginAction(this.gatherLoginData())
        }
        // ==this.props.navigation.navigate('Test');
    }

    onBtnGrpPress = selectedIndex => {
        this.setState({ selectedIndex })
    }

    onTosAcceptPress = () => {
        this.setState({ tosModalVisible: false })
        this.props.valueChange({
            storeName: 'settings',
            prop: 'TOSAccepted',
            value: true
        })
    }

    modalClose = () => {
        this.setState({ inputModalVisible: false })
    }

    onDownloadSettingsPress = () => {
        // this.modalClose();
        Keyboard.dismiss()
        this.props.getSettingsFromUrl(this.state.inputValue)
    }

    render() {
        const { selectedIndex } = this.state
        const {
            settings,
            app: {
                errorMessages: { login: errorId }
            }
        } = this.props.state
        const { userName, unitName, saveUsername, isDayTime } = settings
        const {
            vehiclelogin,
            employee1login,
            employee2login,
            mileagelogin
        } = settings.general

        const inputs1 = [
            { name: 'unitName', label: 'Unit', placeholder: 'Enter a Unit', visible: true },
            { name: 'userName', label: 'Username', placeholder: 'Enter a Username', visible: true },
            {
                name: 'password',
                label: 'Password',
                placeholder: 'Enter a Password',
                secureTextEntry: true,
                visible: true
            },
            { name: 'Mileage', label: 'Mileage', placeholder: 'Enter a Mileage', visible: (mileagelogin || mileagelogin === undefined) },
        ]

        const inputs2 = [
            { name: 'Vehicle', label: 'Vehicle', placeholder: 'Enter a Vehicle', visible: (vehiclelogin || vehiclelogin === undefined) },
            { name: 'EmployeeNumber1', label: 'Employee #1', placeholder: 'Enter Employee #1', visible: (employee1login || employee1login === undefined) },
            { name: 'EmployeeNumber2', label: 'Employee #2', placeholder: 'Enter Employee #2', visible: (employee2login || employee2login === undefined) },
        ]

        // console.log(this.props.state);

        return (
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView
                contentContainerStyle={[
                    styles.container,
                    { backgroundColor: isDayTime ? colors.white : colors.black }
                ]}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        width: m(200),
                        height: m(200),
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        marginVertical: h(5)
                    }}
                >
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                        onPress={() =>
                            Alert.alert(
                                'Version: ' +
                                    config.appVersion +
                                    `\nRelease Date: ${config.releaseDate}`
                            )
                        }
                    >
                        <Image
                            style={{ height: null, width: null, flex: 1 }}
                            source={images.logo}
                        />
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
                    <Text center bold normal>
                        Enter the information below to login to EnRoute Mobile
                    </Text>
                </View>

                <View
                    style={{
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'space-between',
                        marginHorizontal: h(20)
                    }}
                >
                    <Text small>Remember Username | Unit Login?</Text>
                    <ButtonGroup
                        buttons={buttons}
                        selectedButtonStyle={{ backgroundColor: colors.black }}
                        selectedTextStyle={{ color: colors.white }}
                        selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
                        containerBorderRadius={5}
                        onPress={this.onBtnGrpPress}
                        textStyle={{ paddingVertical: h(3), fontSize: m(12) }}
                        containerStyle={{ width: '30%', height: h(30) }}
                    />
                </View>

                <Text normal bold center style={{ marginVertical: h(10) }}>
                    All Fields Are Case Sensitive
                </Text>

                <Formik
                    onSubmit={values => console.log('values:', values)}
                    initialValues={
                        saveUsername
                            ? { userName, unitName }
                            : { userName: '', unitName: '' }
                    }
                >
                    {props => {
                        this.formikProps = props
                        return (
                            <View>
                                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginHorizontal: 2 }}>
                                        {inputs1.map((item, i) => {
                                          if (!item.visible) {
                                            return null
                                          }
                                          return (
                                            <FormInput
                                                key={item.name}
                                                {...item}
                                                {...props}
                                                lastElement={i === inputs1.length - 1}
                                                onSubmitEditing={() =>
                                                    this.onSubmitEditing(i, props)
                                                }
                                                refInput={el =>
                                                    (this['input' + i] = el)
                                                }
                                                returnKeyType="next"
                                            />
                                        )})}
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginHorizontal: 2 }}>
                                        {inputs2.map((item, i) => {
                                          if (!item.visible) {
                                            return null
                                          }
                                          return (
                                            <FormInput
                                                key={item.name}
                                                {...item}
                                                {...props}
                                                lastElement={i === inputs2.length - 1}
                                                onSubmitEditing={() =>
                                                    this.onSubmitEditing(inputs1.length + i, props)
                                                }
                                                refInput={el =>
                                                    (this['input' + (4 + i)] = el)
                                                }
                                                returnKeyType="next"
                                            />
                                        )})}
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                                <Button
                                    label='Login'
                                    labelStyle={styles.buttonText}
                                    buttonStyle={styles.button}
                                    onPress={() => this.onLoginPress(props)}
                                />
                            </View>
                        )
                    }}
                </Formik>
                <View style={{ marginTop: h(5) }}>
                    {
                        <Text red mini center>
                            {errorId && errorId.toString()}
                        </Text>
                    }
                </View>
                <Button
                    size={40}
                    containerViewStyle={styles.settingsButton}
                    image={'settings'}
                    onPress={() =>
                        this.props.navigation.navigate({
                            routeName: 'SettingsStack',
                            key: 'settings',
                            params: { prevStack: 'Login' }
                        })
                    }
                />

                <TosModal
                    isVisible={this.state.tosModalVisible}
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                    onAcceptPress={this.onTosAcceptPress}
                    onModalHide={() =>
                        this.setState({ inputModalVisible: true })
                    }
                />

                <InputModal
                    isVisible={this.state.inputModalVisible}
                    value={this.state.inputValue}
                    onChangeText={value => this.setState({ inputValue: value })}
                    onPress={this.onDownloadSettingsPress}
                    modalClose={this.modalClose}
                />
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(state => ({ state }), actions)(Login)

let paddingTop = 0

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    paddingTop = 20
}
if (isIphoneX()) {
    paddingTop = 40
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingTop,
        flexGrow: 1,
        backgroundColor: colors.white,
        paddingHorizontal: w(20),
        paddingBottom: h(20)
    },
    headerContainer: {
        backgroundColor: colors.darkGray,
        padding: w(5),
        borderRadius: w(5),
        marginVertical: h(5)
    },
    button: {
        width: '80%',
        borderRadius: w(5),
        backgroundColor: colors.lightGray,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: h(10)
    },
    buttonText: {
        color: colors.black,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    settingsButton: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? paddingTop : 0,
        left: w(10),
        borderRadius: w(30)
    }
})
```

Comment: Which line is line 191?

Comment: <KeyboardAwareScrollView

Comment: This is the full section of line 191 - <KeyboardAwareScrollView
                contentContainerStyle={[
                    styles.container,
                    { backgroundColor: isDayTime ? colors.white : colors.black }
                ]}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
            >

Comment: Try to remove the code from this section, and then add it by piece

Comment: @JB_DELR Tried that but no luck

Comment: So it's probably KeyboardAwareScrollView. Is it normal to pass an array in contentContainerStyle ? Don't you want to merge styles ?
contentContainerStyle={{
                    ...styles.container,
                     backgroundColor: isDayTime ? colors.white : colors.black
               }}

Comment: @JB_DELR Yea...tried that too - contentContainerStyle={{...styles.container, backgroundColor: isDayTime ? colors.white : colors.black }}  - Still same issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. (React-native )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137676/warning-functions-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the issue was with the package keyboard aware scroll view. Needed to update the package to the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried flattening the style? like:
`contentContainerStyle={Stylesheet.flatten([ styles.container, { backgroundColor: isDayTime ? colors.white : colors.black }])}`
You can find the doc [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet)